# Forward packets with specific IP address with Scapy

Tags: ip, scapy, sniffing

with Scapy I can sniff packets and filter by destination.

```
sniff(filter="dst <ip addr>")
```

How do I use Scapy to only forward packets that are being sent to that specific ip address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the prn argument for sniff like this

```
sniff(filter="your ip address", prn=process_packet)
```

Where process_packet is a method that do what you need, like this

```
def process_packet(pkt):
    here you do what you need with the sniffed packet
```

Sniff function will apply process_packet to every packet that is sniffed.

Hope this is what you asked.